# delete a node in linked list using pointers

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to write a method that gets a linked list (**pplist) and an address to the item I want to delete (*pplaneToDelete).
this is what I wrote and the program crashes. any help?

```
void DeleteAirplane(plane **pplist, plane *pplaneToDelete) {
plane *cur = pplist, *prev = NULL;

if (cur = pplaneToDelete) {

    pplist =cur->next_plane;
    free(cur);
}
while ((cur != pplaneToDelete) && (cur != NULL)) {
    prev = cur;
    cur = cur->next_plane;
}
if (cur != NULL) {
    prev->next_plane = cur->next_plane;
    free(cur);
}
}
```

**edit:**
i changed to:

```
void DeleteAirplane(plane **pplist, plane *pplaneToDelete) {
plane *cur = *pplist, *prev = NULL;

if (cur == pplaneToDelete) {
    *pplist =cur->next_plane;
    free(cur);
    return;
}
while ((cur != pplaneToDelete) && (cur != NULL)) {
    prev = cur;
    cur = cur->next_plane;
}
if (cur != NULL) {
    prev->next_plane = cur->next_plane;
    free(cur);
}
}
```

it works!
any comments?

Comment: `(cur = pplaneToDelete)` is assignment not comparison. You should use `(cur == pplaneToDelete)` Also `plane *cur = pplist` should be `plane *cur = *pplist` and `pplist =cur->next_plane;` should be `*pplist =cur->next_plane;`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar tnx for the comment. can you please explain your tow last arguments? i dont fully understand

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. The error is in the second line. Did you get any compilation warnings?

Comment: @n.m. yeah, it didn't compile. I've edited the code and now its ok

Comment: Note: you dont need the special case for the node_to_delete beeing at the start of the list.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. Next time, when you have a "why is this crashing?" question, be sure to include information like what error you're getting and what line is causing the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems here.

1. `(cur = pplaneToDelete)` is assignment not comparison
   hence change it to `(cur == pplaneToDelete)`.
2. `pplist` is pointer to pointer, hence you need to de-reference it to get the pointer object it is holding.

   `plane *cur = pplist` --> `plane *cur = *pplist`

   `pplist =cur->next_plane;` --->`*pplist =cur->next_plane;`
3. You need to `return` after deleting head node, otherwise you will invoke undefined behavior trying to access `cur` pointer.

   `if (cur == pplaneToDelete) {
       *pplist =cur->next_plane;
       free(cur);
       return; // Node deleted now return.
   }`